# Develop the context free grammar to match this language (puzzle)

Tags: context-free

This is a puzzle type question which asks to create a context-free grammar to match this language:

```
{ x#w | x,w are in {a,b}*, and w contains the reversal of x as a substring }
```

So some example strings to try:
    #, a#a, b#b, ab#ba, ab#aaabbba

Does anyone have any advice on how to get better at these types of problems?  I am generally a good problem solver, but have trouble developing grammars for languages for some reason.  I am completely stuck on this question.  Here is my attempt:

```
S --> TR
T --> aTa | bTb | #R
R --> RR | 0 | 1 | empty
```

My guess is that we want to define the left side of the string in terms of the right side of the string.

Edit:  As far as I can tell, the above answer seems to be correct now.  Only took me an hour to figure out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following grammar:
$$ T \to aTa | bTb $$
It is not hard to check that $T \to^* wTw^R$ for all $w \in \{a,b\}^*$, where $w^R$ is the reverse of $w$.

The language we are aiming at is $\{w\#xw^Ry : w,x,y \in \{a,b\}^*\}$. We can take care of the $x$ part by providing a "leaf case" for $T$:
$$
\begin{align*}
&T \to \#R \\
&R \to aR|bR|\epsilon
\end{align*}
$$
Similarly, to take care of the $y$ part, we can create a new start symbol $S$, and add the production
$$ S \to TR $$
In total, we obtain the grammar
$$
\begin{align*}
&S \to TR \\
&T \to aTa|bTb|\#R \\
&R \to aR|bR|\epsilon
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 2):

```
X --> Xa | Xb | Y

Y --> aYa | bYb | #Z

Z --> Za | Zb | empty
```

Y is the part that handles the string reversal. X and Z handle junk to the right and left of the reversal of `x`.

Comment: Mind explaining verbally how you approached solving this, thinking up the answer etc?  I eventually figured this out, but it took me way too long.  If I had to do this in a short time, I would be screwed.  I need a more systematic way to approach these.

Comment: @Musicode: I would, but I don't understand my own thought process. Sorry.